# How do I add a button on other UI element to a Google spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to add a ToggleButton to a Google Spreadsheet. I would like to be able to control the positioning and the text on the button. Is this possible?

If so, does anyone know of a good tutorial that covers these topics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not interact with the spreadsheet environment UI except by adding a menu.

You can insert a drawing or an image and assign a function to it but the positioning of that "button" is only manual and not accessible programatically.

So,... unless you try to entirely recreate the spreadsheet layout in a personalized UI (which would be quite hard I guess /-) you have no way to do what you want.

I would suggest (as someone famous once said) 'Think differently'

Comment: Thank you, Serge. I was afraid you would say that. However, I do remember seeing some code which employed a panel into which one could insert a GUI element. I haven't been able to locate that tutorial again and I don't know how to position the panel if I did pursue that approach.

Comment: adding a [UI panel in a spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/uiapp?hl=fr-FR#DisplayingSpreadsheet) is pretty simple but this panel can't be positioned other than manually and its size is never really small...